# How to pass parameters to an App service's source control?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have some installation files and filetexts that i hosted in a repository that i need to have within an Appservice. I am currently using a sourcecontrol as shown below, but i need to pass parameters to one of those files in my repo; is there a way of passing parameters from my ARM template to that repo besides sourcecontrols just after the creation of the App service?

```
      {
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "web",
      "type": "sourcecontrols",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('sites_name'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', parameters('sites_name'), '/config/web')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoUrl')]",
        "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
        "IsManualIntegration": true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't believe this is possible. Parameters are used against Azure resources in the ARM template and I don't see anything in the [Sourcecontrol API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/sourcecontrols) that would allow for file execution. One workaround that might work is [create a site extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-web-sites-extensions/) your site object depend on that will accept that parameters your passing and perform the executed action.